# concatColumn pops out UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, dataframe, csv

I am doing a simple Data Frame that can read and write CSV while being able to edit the data. I have encountered a problem when I am trying to concatenate a new column to my data frame.

This is the sample input of the file:

```
Name,Age,Salary
Lim,20,2000
Tan,20,3000
Mah,19,2500
Roger,10,4000
```

And this is my code to concatenate the columns :

```
String filePath = "\...\Book1.csv";

String line;
List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        List<String> column = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
        data.add(column);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

System.out.println(data.toString());

String [] newColumn = {"Colour", "Green", "Blue", "Black","Yellow"};
for(int i = 0 ; i<data.size(); i++){
    List<String> temp = data.get(i);
    temp.add(newColumn[i]);
}

System.out.println(data.toString());
```

The output will be like this :

```
[[Name, Age, Salary], [Lim, 20, 2000], [Tan, 20, 3000], [Mah, 19, 2500], [Roger, 10, 4000]]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:111)
    at Testing.main(Testing.java:31)

System.out.println(data.toString());
```

How am I going to change the code to be able to read the `newColumn` and store it into `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadoc for Arrays.asList:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array

You need to create a new ArrayList if you wish to add to it.

```
List<String> column = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
```

Comment: means that I should declare a variable `temp` and it is an empty arrayList? 
After that I read all the data from the `data` and add in `newColumn` together into the `temp` ?